# Is it possible to have a database under MySQL export rows into managed folders accessible to the web?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, http, apache2

Is it possible to have a database under MySQL export rows into managed folders accessible to the web with the contents of each column be it's own text file OR json file?

To be honest, I can't find anywhere on how to do this?
My question seems to be quite niché.

Ill break down my problem.
lets say I have a database, with a table called "registry"
under registry, I would have 4 columns.
for example:

```
username nickname dob      timestamp
bob2414  bobby   03211989   201019
sarah83  sars    10162002   231019
masterc  carlo   07271997   261019
blahhbh  umomi   03241999   281119
```

is there a way, upon a new entry, to trigger either a JS bot, or any kind of automation to create a structure on the web that could be called upon, for example.

```
domain.com/registry
                bob2414/
                    nickname.txt
                    dob.txt
                    timestamp.txt
                    (or)
                    bob2414.json
                sarah83/
                    nickname.txt
                    dob.txt
                    timestamp.txt
                    (or)
                    sarah83.json
                masterc/
                    nickname.txt
                    dob.txt
                    timestamp.txt
                    (or)
                    masterc.json
```

and so on?

is there a page i can view, or any video explanation online?
Are there any better ways I can do this?

The application of my problem lies within creating these directories, as I don't want one huge json file hanging around, because i plan on these files being downloaded and accessed, and want smoother download times then managing a huge database.

The same would also apply to after I delete a row, would it manage to be deleted on its own?

please, and thank you. Ill help any way I can!

Comment: The trigger is executed on the MySQL server. can't be used to trigger other script
So, I would say this is not quite possible -- at least not simply.
check this
https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with a personal thought experiment.

In theory it would be easier to design an element in PHP to query the database with a GET request, and have data presented in JSON format, than to worry about managing files and directories with a java or javascript applet